# Why the error in coming while creating a JIRA issue using REST API (C#)?

Tags: c#, json, jira, jira-rest-api

I am working on a requirement where I need to create multiple issues in one go by Using the REST API. However, I start with uploading a single issue because I am new in API integration. I write few lines of code in c#. Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        JiraCreateIssueRequest jcir = new JiraCreateIssueRequest();
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        string sUsername = "aaa@xyz.com";
        string sPassword = "TestPassword";
        string uri = @"https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue";
        Uri address = new Uri(uri);
        HttpWebRequest request;
        //HttpWebResponse response = null;
        StreamReader sr;
        string sData = null;
        string returnXML = string.Empty;
        if (address == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("address"); }
        //jcir.project.ID = 100;
        //jcir.Summary = "This issue is created by JIRA REST Api";
        //jcir.Description = "This issue is created by JIRA REST Api";
        //jcir.IssueType.ID = 1;
        sData = @"{""fields"":{""project"":{""key"": ""SITT""},""summary"": ""REST API Uploading"",""description"":""Creating an issue via REST API"",""issuetype"": {""name"": ""Test""}}}";
        //sData = jcir.ToString();
        try
        {
            // Create and initialize the web request
            request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            // Add the Authorization header to the web request
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sUsername, sPassword);
            //Write Data
            if (sData != null)
            {
                byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sData);
                // Set the content length in the request headers
                request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
                // Write data
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
                }
                // Get response
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    // Get the response stream
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            // This exception will be raised if the server didn't return 200 - OK
            // Try to retrieve more information about the error
            if (wex.Response != null)
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wex.Response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string sError = string.Format("The server returned '{0}' with the status code {1} ({2:d}).",
                        errorResponse.StatusDescription, errorResponse.StatusCode,
                        errorResponse.StatusCode);
                        sr = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                        returnXML = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (errorResponse != null) errorResponse.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(wex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class JiraCreateIssueRequest
    {
        protected JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        public JiraProject project = new JiraProject();
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public JiraIssueType IssueType = new JiraIssueType();

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return jss.Serialize(this);
        }
    }

    public class JiraCreateIssueResponse
    {


    }

    public class JiraProject
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        //public string Key { get; set; }
    }

    public class JiraIssueType
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        //public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I am running the above code, I am getting the '400' error. I googled it and found that this usually this error comes when the URL or the Username/Password are incorrect. I cross checked both the things however its correct.

May I know why this error is coming or what will be the resolution of the problem?

Comment: Http 400 comes because the server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, too large size, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing. Can you check if all the properties of request are present.

Comment: Thanks Bhaskar, the issue has been resolved. I made some changea in the properties and Json data. Moreover, can you please guide me how to create an Epic issue type in Jira. This code is working fine for normal issue type, however it does not work for Epic issue type.

Answer (score 0):

Your password is not your login password, it's an API token that you get from here:

https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens

Generate a token, then use that as your password.